# docker-compose up rebuilds image after reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on my development machine and using a postgres database image into which I load a fairly large amount of data (takes ~15 minutes to load the whole thing). I have a secondary image which reads data from this database as part of my application. Since I don't intend to change anything in the database once I load the data into it, I don't want it to rebuild the image every time I run docker-compose up. To avoid that I always call

`docker-compose build my_flask`

`docker-compose up`

But it seems that after I reboot my computer, calling `docker-compose up` decides to rebuild the postgres image anyway, forcing me to sit through the lengthy loading process any time I reboot the computer. How can I stop this from happening?

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:

  postgis:
    image: mdillon/postgis 
    hostname: leni_prototype_postgis
    container_name: leni_prototype_postgis
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    expose:
      - "5432"
      - "22"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./mnt/pg_init_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:z
    restart: always

  flask_server:
    build: ./flask/Docker/
    hostname: my_flask
    container_name: my_flask
    networks:
      - my-network
    expose:
      - "5005"
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    volumes:
      - ./flask/Docker/app/grass_data:/grass_data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - postgis
    restart: always

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: How do you know that the image is being rebuilt? How do you know that something else is not causing the the delay?

Comment: @7_R3X I can see in the terminal output that it is going through the process of inserting the data (a constantly scrolling list of `INSERT 1 0`)

Comment: Did you load the data inside the container or the image? Can you see the output of the image being built?

Answer (score -1):

You need to persist the database data folder if you don't want it to be initialized each time:

```
    volumes:
      - ./mnt/pg_init_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:z
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why? I will give this a try.

Comment: Please try the solution yourself.